# Using requireLocalization and getLocalization in Dojo

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, dojo

I am trying to create a custom Dojo widget this is how my file structure looks:

```
customwidget
  |
  +--nls
  |   |
  |   +--en
  |       |
  |       +--CustomWidget.js (My localization code)
  +--CustomWidget.js (My actual custom widget code)
```

Now in my code I am writing:

```
dojo.requireLocalization("customwidget", "CustomWidget", "en");
```

And to get this localization I write:

```
dojo.i18n.getLocalization('timeago', "Timeago", "en")
```

There are quite a few lines of code in my widget and it works with the localization in **customwidget > nls > en**. But the problem is in my Google Chrome's console following error shows up:

```
GET http://******/******/******/customwidget/nls/CustomWidget.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Why does Dojo need the localization code file inside "customwidget > nls" also? Despite the error in console my code runs actually without any problem.

I was going through the [Globalization Guidelines](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/quickstart/internationalization/globalization-guidelines/locale-and-resource-bundle-guidelines.html), and it says that instead of writing `dojo.requireLocalization("my.app", "bar", "zh-cn");` we should use `dojo.requireLocalization("my.app", "bar");`. Same is the case with `dojo.i18n.getLocalization`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I'm not entirely certain why it still makes the request (IMO it shouldn't) but dojo is trying to get the default language bundle. It's good practice to have a default bundle at the root of the nls folder, so that *something* is displayed when a user with an unsupported language browses the page.

For the second question - you should be allowing dojo to choose the correct language bundle, surely if you specify it yourself you'll end up replicating a lot of code deciding which language to use and passing that around.